# having problems running these command VS code to create a react app

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie to react. trying to run create a react app command on my mac terminal but this keeps popping up. I need help as I a working on a front end developer.

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall access
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
>   npm ERR!  stack:
>   npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
>   npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
>   npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
>   npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/wahab/.npm/_logs/2019-01-14T17_39_00_181Z-debug.log
>   wahabs-MacBook-Pro:web projects wahab$ node --version
>   v10.15.0
>   wahabs-MacBook-Pro:web projects wahab$ node --version
>   v10.15.0
>   wahabs-MacBook-Pro:web projects wahab$ npm install -g create-react-app
>   npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall access
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
>   npm ERR!   stack:
>   npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
>   npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
>   npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
>   npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

Comment: What command do you run_

Comment: npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: It has nothing to do with command, you should learn about terminal and super user.

Answer (score 0):

Not a viable solution on the long term, because it seems that you have access issues that you should fix. In the meantime, you can do that, prepend `sudo` in front of your command to execute it with admin rights.

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```